# How to return worksheet or workbook name in cell

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am trying to create a code that outputs the date (e.g. 201607) contained within the workbook name (e.g. 20160701_tyo). In the following code, I specify which cell to output the value, but I always run into an error that I didn't "define my object". What am I missing?

```
Sub WorksheetDateName()
    Dim DateName As String, OnlyDate As Long
    DateName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    OnlyDate = Left(DateName.Value, 6)
    ActiveWorksheet.Range("E1").Value = OnlyDate
End Sub
```

Also, would it be possible to perform something similar for "ActiveSheet" in addition to "ActiveWorkbook"? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's `Activesheet`.

Comment: Try `OnlyDate = Left(DateName, 6)` You defined `DateName As String` so it's not an object and it have not any properties or methods that you can invoke with `.` so `DateName.Value` makes no sense at all because it is not an object. Also,, as @SJR said, try `ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value = OnlyDate`. Object `ActiveWorksheet` does not exist.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - indeed, why is that not the error?

Comment: @SJR what do you mean?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - OP says error message is "didn't "define my object" which isn't right as that is not a valid message, but however I try it I can't get a related error message anyway.

Comment: Your point raises an "Invalid qualifier" error. Mine raises 424 or undefined variable depending on whether Option Explicit is on.

Comment: @SJR OP did not specify what error was or what line, but reading the code I detected those fails (but I did not tested), and posted about that. But I totally agree that "define object" is not a valid message :)

Answer (score 3):

For the **Workbook** name, you could use VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 6)
```

Or you could just use a formula in `E1` such as:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))+1,6)
```

---

For the **Worksheet** name, if you wanted the first 6 characters you could use VBA:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 6)
```

and the equivalent formula would be:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,6)
```

***Note: both Excel formula require that the file has been saved at least once previously to work correctly.***

---

Looking through your code though, one way to 'fix' it would be to use `Val` to convert the 6 character string to a value, that can be held in the `Long`.

```
Sub WorksheetDateName()
    Dim DateName As String, OnlyDate As Long
    DateName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    OnlyDate = Val(Left(DateName, 6))
    ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Value = OnlyDate
End Sub
```

You'll also note I've changed `ActiveWorksheet` to `Activesheet` - as other comments have suggested.